# Make Pycharm see packages in subdirectory, without adding it as a source root

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-import

Let's say I have a project with structure

```
parent/
    one.py
    sub/
        two.py
        three.py
```

Where file `two.py` is

```
x = 42
```

And `three.py`:

```
from two import x

print(x)
```

The import statement in `three.py` will work correctly as these files lie in the same directory, but the PyCharm will mark the import as an **Unresolved reference**:

[image: Screenshot]

One way to fix that is to ask PyCharm to mark the directory `sub` as the sources root. But then the files inside `sub` will be visible to all the other files in the project, e.g. in `one.py`. But I would like to avoid this.

The other way would be to write imports as `import sub.two`. which I do right now in my project. But this is quite annoything since I have a deep folder structure.

Is there any other way to do it?

**UPD:**
Changing import statement to

```
from .two import x
```

Would cause a error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.two'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Also I observed, if I try to use relative import from a parent directory, e.g.

```
from ..one import y
```

I am getting

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

So I would suspect this has something to do with my project configuration and relative imports work from the top-level directory of the project. I will try to dig in deeper, but I would still appreciate some answer from those, who might have already encountered this problem.

Comment: Relative import with `from .two import x`?

Comment: Someone gave the same answer, which was deleted for some reason.
If I do relative import I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.extract_and_plot_sphere'; '__main__' is not a package`. Any idea why it happens?

Comment: Yes, because you are trying to import a module that is not part of a package. I would recommend against having modules on top level that are imported by other modules. This just pollutes the namespace and may sooner or later become a problem when some library tries to import a module with the same name.

Comment: Are we discussing the same thing? I was talking about importing two.py to three.py. They are in the same directory, which is not the top-level directory. Do i always have to include full path (relative to top-level) to the module in order to import it?

Comment: You can include `two` to `three` simply by `import two`. But Pycharm doesn't ”know”. Take this as a hint that this is discouraged. When you have more than one module, better put them into a package and don't expect `import something` to import the `something` in the same package, use `import packagename.something` or `import .something` to be *sure* you get the `something` you really want. And make the package explicitly known to PyCharm.

Comment: It seems to me you have a somewhat ”unhealthy” mix of directories and packages and potentially execute modules within packages by directly executing them. There lies madness, because then there are multiple ways of importing the same modules which leads to modules actually executed more than once and classes and functions that are equal but not the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am still trying to figure how to do better structure for my project, and how am I supposed to use packaging. Are there any good guides on this topic? 
In your comment, by saying 'create a package' - do you mean - add __init__ file and add package directory to python path?

I am still trying to figure out how my project structure and import practices should look like, it's a scientific project, but the ammount of code is already quite big for one person..

Comment: Yes `__init__.py` and adding the toplevel directory to `sys.path`. Not any directories within package directories, and don't execute modules in packages as programs directly but via `python -m some_package.subpackage.module`.

Comment: But does __init__.py really matter since Python 3.3? See "The missing __init__.py trap" http://ncoghlan-devs-python-notes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html

Comment: Well, yes and no, I prefer explicit packages with `__init__.py`. Without it there is a chance implicit packages on the path will be picked up that where not meant to be packages.